# How to use an excel formula to validate an customized email address?

Tags: regex, excel, vba, excel-formula, email-validation

I'm very new to excel VBA macro and I just want to right an excel formula to validate an email which has been customized. For an example the email that I'm finding, must end up with '@gmail.com' and must reject following mail items;

1. [no word]@gmail.com
2. [space]@gmail.com
3. xxx@gmail.com[any word]
4. xxx@gmail..com
5. xxx@gmail/.com
6. xxx@gmail/com

To validate the email address I have written a regex as follows;

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@(\b(gmail)\b)+(\.\b(com)\b)$
```

I tried different ways to apply these regex in to an excel formula like =MATCH but it did not work. I need to complete this email validation using an excel formula only.

I'm grateful if someone can help me on this?

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/XioSzC/2) help?

Comment: @Mandy8055 Yes that is helpful. Could you tell me how to use this in an excel formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you use the regex inside excel; you need to setup VB inside to be able to use it. Please follow the below steps:

**Steps to Add VBA reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5**

- Select "Developer" tab ([**I cannot find this tab what to do?**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx))
- Select "Visual Basic" icon from 'Code' ribbon section
- In "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications" window select "Tools" from the top menu.
- Select "References"
- Check the box next to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" to include in your workbook.
- Click "OK".
- Right-click on your workbook name in the "Project-VBAProject" pane (at the top left corner of the editor window) and select Insert -> Module from the context menu. The screenshot may look like:
  [image]
- Now; inside the module; paste the below function.

```
Function simpleCellRegex(MyVal As String) As String
    
    Dim regEx As New RegExp

    'Below is the flag options'
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "^[\w.-]+@gmail\.com$"
    End With

    If regEx.Test(MyVal) Then
        simpleCellRegex = "Matched"
    Else
        simpleCellRegex = "Not matched"
    End If

End Function
```

Save the whole workbook as **Excel Macro-enabled Workbook instead of Excel workbook** [image]

That's it. You're all set.

Now go to your excel sheet and inside your formulas tab use the above declared macro. I used

**Result:**
[image: Result]

Comment: Very neat. I think you should mention that in VBE, a module needs to inserted and there above code shall be pasted. Otherwise it will not appear as a UDF.

Comment: @Mandy8055 Yes, I'll check that too.

Comment: Thanks to @JvdV for adding improvements to the code in above answer.

Answer (score 2):

While you have mentioned what to avoid, you have not really mentioned what exactly to match. It's hard to imagine you'd want to match something like `....@gmail.com` or `___@gmail.com` and `__.__@gmail.com` so therefor a little bit more secure would be:

```
^(?!_+(?:[.-]?_*)*)\w+(?:[-.]?\w+)*@gmail\.com$
```

See the online [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jxs04G/5). It's not perfect but may take care of a number of cases you actually need the match to fail.

To call this as an UDF, you may use:

```
Function REGEXMATCH(str As String, pat As String) As Boolean
    
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = pat
        REGEXMATCH = .Test(str)
    End With

End Function
```

You can now call this using `=REGEXMATCH(A1,"^(?!_+(?:[.-]?_*)*)\w+(?:[-.]?\w+)*@gmail\.com$")`

[image]

Note I used late binding on the regexp object. It's a personal preference and may come in handy when you need to distribute the project.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This is so flexible.